# WPF: How do I position the mouse cursor in code?

Tags: wpf, position, move, mouse-cursor

I am implementing the system menu (Restore, Move, Size...) on a borderless window, and I want the mouse cursor to move to the center of the Window when size or move is selected.

Ideally in VB but C# is fine as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SetCursorPos` function, something like:

```
Declare Function SetCursorPos& Lib "user32" (ByVal p As Point)

'...

dim p as point
p.x = 100
p.y = 200
SetCursorPos p
```

Answer (score 1):

A few tweaks and it seems to work:

```
Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Int32, ByVal Y As Int32) As Int32
```

...

```
With Win

  Dim left As Int32 = CInt(.Left + .Width - CURSOR_OFFSET_MEDIUM)
  Dim top As Int32 = CInt(.Top + .Height / 2)

  SetCursorPos(left, top)

End With
```